# What kind of variable is int * [2]? as in the delcaration int* p2[2]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int* p1;
```

Is just a pointer. When used with new[] it can be incremented like an array or iterator. That's fine, but what is

```
int* p2[2];
```

It looks like it should be a pointer to an array with two elements, right? But if I make a two element array, I can't point to it. I can't find anyway to make p2 point at something. A lot of the following is just trying different assignments for the heck of it, but p2 = &arr didn't work which really surprised me. So what is a int* [2] and how is it different from an int (*) [2]?

```
int main()
{
    int arr[2];

    int* p1;            //pointer to int, can be used like an array
    int* p2[2];         //pointer to an array


    p1 = new int[2];
    p1 = arr;
    //p1 = &arr;        //cannot convert ‘int (*)[2]’ to ‘int*’ in assignment

    //p2 = &arr;        //incompatible types in assignment of ‘int (*)[2]’ to ‘int* [2]’
    //p2 = &p1;         //incompatible types in assignment of ‘int**’ to ‘int* [2]’

    //p2 = new int[2];  //incompatible types in assignment of ‘int*’ to ‘int* [2]’
    //p2 = arr;         //incompatible types in assignment of ‘int [2]’ to ‘int* [2]’


}
```

Comment: `int* p2[2];` is an array of two pointers to `int`. Use [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int*+p2%5B2%5D) when you're not sure what a declaration like this means.

Comment: Of course it is. Just one of those days...

Comment: If you want a pointer to an array, that would be `int (*p2)[2];`. Note that in this case, the array size is significant--if (for example) you increment `p2`, it'll increment by the size of an array of 2 `int`s.

Comment: @PaulR: Or install the `cdecl` command-line program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array of 2 elements, being each element a pointer to an `int`.

cdecl.org is your friend for these tasks:

[image]

Comment: Paul R pointed this out in a comment. Very obvious in the right mindset.

Comment: I remember the great HELPPC utility for DOS (which had a resident mode to bring up the program at any time) and it had some examples of complex C variable declarations. Was a good training at the time :D

Comment: Seems that there is an online version of the HELPPC database. This was the topic: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/c_declarations.html

Answer (score 0):

`p2` is an *array* of pointers to `int`, whose size is 2. You can store `p1` in `p2` with:

```
p2[i] = p1;
```

If you wanted a *pointer* to an array you'd have:

```
int (*ptr)[2];
```

You may want to read up on the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), an easy way to understand more elaborated declarations.

Answer (score 0):

A handy way to decipher complicated-looking declarations is to read from right to left:

```
int* p2[2];
```

If you [read from right to left](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220613320_Reading_types_in_C_using_the_right_left_walk_method), you get: *Array with two elements that are pointers to `int`.*